# mysql query with case statement returning one row incorrectly

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query that pulls domains that are related (from domain_related) and uses CASE to help make the results neater. The problem is this one of the rows returned is wrong as it returns the domain_name of 666 instead of 665:

```
SELECT case when domain_related.domain_id = '666' then domain_related.domain2_id else domain_related.domain_id end as domain_id, domain.domain_name
FROM domain_related
JOIN domain ON domain.domain_id=domain_related.domain2_id
WHERE '666' in (domain_related.domain_id,domain_related.domain2_id)

665 is actually sofadmiral.net
666 is actually sofranger.it

but the query results are like so:

665 sofranger.it
667 sofmarine.me
668 soffighter.us
669 sofpilot.com
670 sofgeneral.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `domain_id` is an integer or string ? if integer, why need quotes?

Comment: @crashintoty can you add your table structure..

Comment: The 'domain' table is domain_id, domain_name. The 'domain_related' table is domain_related_id, domain_id and domain2_id. The 'domain_related' table looks like this: 1, 665, 666 / 2, 665, 667 / 3, 665, 668... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of tweaking and no success, I finally looked for another way of writing this query and found it in utilizing the UNION command/function (see below). The results returned are perfect. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
SELECT domain_id, domain_name
FROM domain
WHERE domain_id IN (
    SELECT domain_id as domain_id
    FROM domain_related
    WHERE domain2_id = 666
    UNION
    SELECT domain2_id as domain_id
    FROM domain_related
    WHERE domain_id = 666
)
```